# Foreach thread.join, does not work as expected, how to fix?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I want to run some method in few threads, this method take some argument.
When I try to execute this, my test not passed on it, because some thread not working to end. But, at the end of function I use `Foreach { thread.join }`
Here is my code: (Paths - List of some objects. Parse - method with obj from Paths.)

```cs
public void RunAsync()
{
    Thread[] threadArr = new Thread[Paths.Count];
    var pathsArr = Paths.ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < PathsArr.Length; i++)
    {
        threadArr[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Parse));
        threadArr[i].Start((PathsArr[i]));
    }

    foreach (var thread in threadArr)
    {
        thread.Join();
    }
}
```

How can I fix it or which construction/techniques need to use in that case?
I want to do this in few thread because to do this synchronously is too much long.

Comment: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=netframework-4.8) state that 'The caller will block indefinitely if the thread does not terminate.' So if on of your threads does not finish, your calling thread gets blocked. You need to find out, why on of your threads isn't finishing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But my main thread is executed perfectly every time, only from time to time return value not meet test expect (for example only 48 object returned when 50 is expected).  I would like to understand whether the Foreach { thread.join } design can not be performed correctly?

Comment: Using Tasks and awaiting all might be a decent substitute. And [Thread.SetApartmentState()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate).

Comment: @Jimi ooops ...

Comment: @Kasp.Me Why use raw threads instead of eg Parallel.Invoke or Parallel.ForEach? Creating new threads is expensive. Parallel uses threads from a thread pool. Even if you want to use raw threads it's best to use the ThreadPool class instead of creating raw threads. You could replace all that code with eg `Parallel.ForEach(Paths,Parse)` assuming Parse is thread-safe. If Parse returned the result instead of storing it in a shared location, you could write `var results=Paths.AsParallel().Select(x=>Parse(x)).ToArray()`

Comment: @Kasp.Me As for what's wrong with the code, you haven't actually posted the code, just generic thread starting and joining code. There's nothing wrong with it. `only 48 object returned when 50 is expected` returned where? Are you *sure* there are no race conditions or improperly handled errors? No `catch{}` blocks that hide errors? Post *that* code instead of assuming something's wrong with a simple loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.Join()` will block you current Thread. This means that every foreach loop will be executed after the last run.

I think you want to `Start()` your threads to execute them parallel.

Here an Example:

```cs
// Example-Work-Method
public static void MyAction(int waitSecs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting MyAction " + waitSecs);
    Thread.Sleep(waitSecs * 1000);
    Console.WriteLine("End MyAction " + waitSecs);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // We create a bunch of actions which we want to executte parallel
    Action[] actions = new Action[]
        {
            new Action(() => MyAction(1)),
            new Action(() => MyAction(2)),
            new Action(() => MyAction(3)),
            new Action(() => MyAction(4)),
            new Action(() => MyAction(5)),
            new Action(() => MyAction(6)),
            new Action(() => MyAction(7)),
            new Action(() => MyAction(8)),
            new Action(() => MyAction(9)),
            new Action(() => MyAction(10)),
        };

    // create a thread for each action
    Thread[] threads = actions.Select(s => new Thread(() => s.Invoke())).ToArray();

    // Start all threads
    foreach (Thread t in threads)
    {
        t.Start();
    }
    // This will "instantly" outputted after start. It won't if we'd use Join()
    Console.WriteLine("All threads are running..");

    // And now let's wait for the work to be done.
    while (threads.Any(t => t.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped))
        Thread.Sleep(100);

    Console.WriteLine("Done..");
}
```

You possibly should ask yourself if you want to call this method `Async`. Async-Methods in c# bring some other mechanics.
Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async